# Combination (piecewise) function of two pre-defined functions

Tags: python, function, curve-fitting, piecewise

I'm currently making a custom function that I will eventually feed into scipy.optimize.curve_fit() for a custom curve fit. My curve fit will be shaped like a bump. Gaussian rise and exponential fall, pieced together at the highest point of the gaussian. I have defined a Gaussian and an exponential function and currently trying to define a combo() function. Here's what I have so far:

```
    def exp(x, a, b, c):
          return a * np.exp((-b * x) + c)
    def gauss(x,d,e,f):
          return d * np.exp(-((x-e)**2)/(2*(f**2)))
    def combo(x,a,b,c,d,e,f):
          ex = exp(x,a,b,c)
          ga = gauss(x,d,e,f)
    num = np.arange(0,1000,1)
    test =combo(num,1,2,3,10,4,3)
```

I've tried to use if statements in my combo function (if x<d: return ga) but I get the error message: "The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()". Maybe this is the solution but I'm not sure how to employ it.

Comment: `x` will be `num`, which is an array and `d` is a scalar (`10`). `x < d` will then also be an array of truth values, which you can't just plug into an `if` and expect it to figure it out - that's why you get that error message. What did you think `x < d` should mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to do this using `numpy` is to use array slicing. Use the mean value, `b`, to mask the values in `x` so that only values prior to or equal to `b` are calculated with the Gaussian function, and the values of `x` greater than `b` are calculated with the exponential function:

```
def exp(x, a, b, c):
    return a * np.exp(-c * (x-b))
def gauss(x, a, b, d):
    return a * np.exp(-((x-b)**2)/(2 * (d**2)))
def combo(x, a, b, c, d):
    y = np.zeros(x.shape)
    y[x <= b] = gauss(x[x <= b], a, b, d)
    y[x > b] = exp(x[x > b], a, b, c)
    return y
num = np.arange(-50, 50, 0.5)
test = combo(num, 10, 4, 3, 3)
```

I assume that you want this function to be continuous, so I changed your parameters so that the values input into `exp` and `gauss` are consistent with each other, and I changed the `arange` parameters so the plot is more meaningful. It looks like the solution you posted will do the piecewise part, but not the continuous part. Presumably the use of `lambda` isn't necessary but not familiar with `np.piecewise`.

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
def combo(x,a,b,c,d,e,f, dtype=np.float64):
    def gauss(x,d,e,f):
        return d * np.exp(-((x-e)**2)/(2*(f**2)))
    def exp(x, a, b, c):
        return a * np.exp((-b * x) + c)
    result = np.piecewise(
        x,
        [x <= e,x > e],
        [lambda x: gauss(x,d,e,f), lambda x: exp(x,a,b,c)],
    )
    return result
```

Comment: to be continuous one would require `a=d` and make it `(x-e)` in the decay as well (without loss of generality)